# not allowing users to enter same value for a field in object

Tags: python, django, forms, django-views

I have this code

** models.py **

```
Class Collection(models.Model):
    user = ForeignKey(User)
    title = Charfield(max_length=250)
    order = IntegerField()
```

I want to allow user to add collection objects. but they have to enter a different number for (order) for every object. for example: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
with limit from 1-10.

I know I can set a unique value for a filed. But, I want all users to be allowed to enter 1-10 for order field

Any idea how to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add Django built-in range validator (1-10) for the Order field and then add the unique constraint on two fields (User, Order).

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator

Class Collection(models.Model):
    user = ForeignKey(User)
    title = Charfield(max_length=250)
    order = IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(10])

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user', 'order',)
```

Comment: Wow totally forgot about unique together meta. Thank you .

Comment: @DjangoGuy If the answer helped, you may consider accepting it.

Comment: It helped a lot it's accepted and I thank you very much for it.